# Is it safe to alter files when the computer is about to shutdown

Tags: c#

**A little information about what I'm trying to do:**
I'm trying to make a simple program in c# that analyses the usage of the computer, how many hours a day does a user use his computer, within those hours how much time does he spend using any application and stuff like that.

**My question is:**
I am trying to do a quick log of the time of shutdown and i need a way for it to be a long term solution without the possibility of corruption.

What is a safe and reliable method of logging that kind of information?

I thought of logging it in an interval of lets say 5 minutes, but what if i am going to make a log at the exact same time the power goes out. There's a chance of corruption and i need a very reliable method to keep this information intact

Comment: Have a look for "TimeSnapper Professional". If you want a good tool for the job.

Comment: @Enigmativity yeah that's what i want, but i was thinking of something more custom, something that also logs the cpu, gpu, memory usage... And i wanted a project to help me get better at presenting statistics. While what you gave me is what i need, i want to make it myself

Comment: You can just run a loop on a separate thread and write the logs to a Text file .

Comment: @preciousbetine Wouldn't that be bad for reliability? what if the power goes out in the middle of the logging and the whole file gets corrupted ?

Comment: It won't get corrupted, use the `System.IO.File` class.

Comment: You can't protect against a sudden power outage shutting down the computer with no ability to run *any* code at that point (and no ability to know ahead of time that it's going to happen). Pick a robust strategy for logging and spend as much time as you like *recovering* things into a clean state when you next start-up - you have so much more time available then, typically.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at SystemEvents.SessionEnding Event :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending?view=netframework-4.7.2

When the event is raised you can capture the shutdown/logoff time in a log entry to a text file to keep things simple and quick.

I have not tested it but I believe that there is a window of a few seconds, In case you want to test out an API call to capture the shutdown timings.

Comment: And where would i save that information? Text file, local database, online? What is the most reliable way for me to have that information as long as i need it?

Comment: aah, thanks for calling it out. Have updated the answer

Comment: Ok, yeah this is good, but I'll have to combine it with a periodic write to a file or database. so in a case of a crash or a power loss i'd still have that information. The only thing that is left now is figuring out the most reliable way to store this information.

Comment: Making database entries wrapped in a transaction should be reliable enough in terms of not getting corrupt or loosing the information even in case of power loss. Any reasons this doesn't work for you ?